# Wine installation of movie maker doesn't work

Tags: software-installation, windows, wine

I'm trying to install movie maker through Wine. I installed wine and the .exe of movie maker. I launched the program via wine, everything works smoothly until this scree at the end:

```
Unable to register the DLL/OCX: RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x1.
```

Click Retry to try again.

Someone can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Wine maintains a list of what programs work well - [https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6183](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6183)

Comment: It probably depends on some DLL included with Windows. Just use a native Linux video editor. You'll get much better performance anyway